# Synching Visual studio with Team services

Tags: azure-devops, visual-studio-2015

I wonder if someone could give me a pointer on this one.  I've started to use Team server with my copy of Visual Studio 2015 community. I'm trying to get all my main solutions synched up, but somehow one of them (Investments4) is showing in team server, but not in my local VS's source control explorer.  Here are the two screens.  Any pointers would be gratefully received.

[image]

[image]

Comment: but do you have this repo locally?

Comment: Yes I do, It's actually in the Local Path that's shown on the source control explorer shot.  I have only just mapped in this path though.  it wasn't mapped when I first started checking in this solution to Team explorer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The investments 4 project is the Git team project, which should not listed in the Source Control explorer. Also you can’t open Source Control Explorer if you connected to Git team project.

You can check files in repositories of Git team project on web access. (open team project in internet explorer > Code > Files)

Comment: Thanks starting.  I've managed to sort it with the help of your answer